# customize query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) FROM tb GROUP BY col1;
```

the result is:

```
col1     COUNT(DISTINCT col2)
----------
A         3
B         4
C         1
D         1
```

I need to customize the query, for example when the col1 is B the result should be:

```
 col1     COUNT(DISTINCT col2)
    ----------
    B         4
```

I used this query:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) FROM tb WHERE col1="B" GROUP BY col1
```

but It returns no rows, It is SQLyog Ultimate- MySQL GUI v11.11. what is wrong with me?
Thanks.

Comment: Use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

Comment: Choose your database:  SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: It is SQLyog Ultimate- MySQL GUI v11.11

Comment: the ' sign dosent work!. It returns no rows.

Answer (score 1):

By "result is `NULL`", I'm guessing that the query is not returning any rows.  This would happen if the `WHERE` condition filters everything out.  This would happen if "B" is not really "B", but has hidden characters, such as spaces at the end or beginning.  Try this version of the query:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2)
FROM tb
WHERE col1 LIKE '%B%'
GROUP BY col1;
```

A more remote possibility is that "B" is a column name.  In that case, using single quotes will fix the problem (in MySQL).

Comment: Why use %B%.user only get those result that col1 is B

Comment: This works, but It returns all rows in col1 which contains 'B', for example it retuens rows such as: B, x B, Y B Z. in fact B is a string!

Comment: @VahidehTabrizi . . . That suggests that you need to refine the `where` to get the value you really want.  The `= 'B'` was not correct; you need to figure out what the correct value is (perhaps `like 'B%'` would work in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) FROM tb WHERE col1='B' GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2)  FROM tb  WHERE col1 LIKE 'B' GROUP BY col1;
```